# setting up general query log in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm using windows 7 and MySQL workbench 6.3

So when I start setting up log file where I could get all queries which are being fired on MySQL database. I stuck so bad.

C:\Program Files\MySQL1\MySQL Server 5.7 and after that there should be any my.ini files according to millions of articles on Google. But I have my-default.ini. :(

Here is my my-default.ini file

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.

[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
# port = .....
# server_id = .....


# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
log=file.log
general-log=1
general-log-file=file.log
```

I have just added the last 3 lines so that I could get log in that file..but am getting nothing not even file file.log in bin.

Can anyone please please help me out to setup this ? Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

First execute below commands to start general log-

```
SET general_log=ON;
```

Now check where your server is writting them by below command-

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'general_log_file';
```

Now go to server and you can read these logs, in linux you can use tail command-

```
tail -f /var/log/mysqd_query.log
```

Note: here path and file is var/log/mysqd_query.log

Comment: if you want to get this setting even after mysql service restart then do this setting in your conf file.

Comment: Makik, I'm on windows 7. After checking SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'general_log_file'; that showed up my log file. But how can I find the path of that file ?

Comment: use same procedure just tail will not work and you can read directly as txt file as content is in readable format or you can use any third party free tool.

Comment: you can also save general logs in table instead of file by log_output=table option but you need service restart for it...after it you can simply read by select query...

Comment: Do I need to ON this variable daily  or once its ON it will keep reading the actions which are being performed on mysql ?

Comment: if you have sufficient space and logs are required then you can update this variable in config file but as it will record every thing i.e. select queries also...so fill space quickly so we should on as per requirement and then off it.